# MySQL Where NOT IN curDATE()

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this:

```
SELECT deals.* FROM deals 
JOIN deals_bookings ON (deals_bookings.deal_id = deals.ID)
WHERE deals_bookings.date > CURDATE()
ORDER BY deals_bookings.date DESC
```

In this, I would like to exclude the deals that are currently active (which have deals_bookings.date = CURDATE() )

So if we pretend these are rows in deals_bookings:

```
deal_id 2 date 2012-02-05
deal_id 3 date 2012-02-05
deal_id 2 date 2012-02-06
deal_id 4 date 2012-02-06
```

This should only return the deal_id 4 row, because it is bigger than the CURDATE() and is not currently active (todays date is 2012-02-05).

Currently it returns deal_id 2 and deal_id 4, because I have not mention to exclude those who currently are active (have a row with curdate())

How can i do this?

Comment: The provided code should be work, what's the question?

Comment: I don't understand your questions. WHy wouldn't the third row qualify? What exactly do you mean by "not currently active"? yOU DEFINED IT AS "which have deals_bookings.date = CURDATE()".

Comment: Currently active are the ones that has the current date, so deals_bookings.date are CURDATE()

Comment: The third row does qualify now, but I dont want it to. Why? Because it is already active today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select d.*
from deals d
join deals_bookings b on d.id = b.deal_id
where b.date > curdate()
  and b.deal_id not in (
    select deal_id
    from deals_bookings
    where date <= curdate()
)
order by b.date desc
```

That would give you what you have now but with the `deals_bookings` values removed if they have an entry with a date on or before today.